# Getting a (autocomplete) list from Wikipedia with writers (of books)

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api, wikidata

I have been trying really hard to get a list of writers of books from Wikipedia using it's API. I would like to give users of my website the ability to show what writers they like. To show them others who like the same writer I thought it would be a good idea to make an autocomlete/suggest textbox which shows them possible writers (after, let's say typing 3 characters). This way, spelling problems are avoided and also I can store the pageId which I can then use to match users.

The coding is not the problem! *The problem is in constructing the right query*. I tried several approaches but I just can't get what I want. There are also very few examples that show how to do this kind of thing.

What I would like:

- returns titles of pages
- pages only (so no categories, revisions etc)
- pages about people, or if possible writers (nationality is unimportant)
- searching on title only

And if possible:

- a little bit of the text on a page (I guess one can only get this on Wikipedia?)
- an url to the page
- date of birth, and when appropriate date of death

I am not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: You can't get date of birth and death from the Wikipedia API. That information is collected in projects as http://dbpedia.org by parsing the [WP:Persondata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Persondata)

Comment: Show us what you have tried, so we know what to start with!

Comment: I thought about including queries I tried, but they are so far away from what I want, I thought it wouldn't be of any help. And they are all quite like examples to be found on the API help pages. It seems that all these examples are aimed at getting data out of Wikipedia for adminstration purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the dbpedia.org tip, i'll check that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying Wikipedia data is nowadays done via its structured data counterpart, Wikidata. https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Data_access

You can for instance use WDQ to get a list of items which are marked as "being" or "having profession of" "writer": http://tools.wmflabs.org/autolist/autolist1.html?q=tree%5B36180%5D%5B%5D%5B31%2C106%5D (60k results).

Or also include all the subclasses thereof (poet and whatever): http://tools.wmflabs.org/autolist/autolist1.html?q=tree%5B36180%5D%5B%5D%5B31%2C106%2C279%5D (gets a bit messy with 200k results, would need some filtering).